# C# HTMLAnchorElement/HTMLinkElement Get OnClick text

Tags: c#, html, wpf, onclick, webbrowser-control

I am trying to use C# System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser in a WPF desktop application to go through a web site. On the site there is a link of the kind:

```
<a href="#" class="query" title="LINK TITLE IS HERE" onclick="javascript:openNewWindow('URL IS HERE', 'ANOTHER TITLE');"> AND HERE ARE SOME MORE TEXT</a>
```

Because I have some problems stopping the links to open on IE instead of my WebBrowser control, I decide to bypass the problem.
So I want to get text from the **onclick**, put it on the **href** and then use the click method to follow the link.

```
 foreach (var el in doc.getElementsByTagName("a")){
  if (el is IHTMLAnchorElement){
    HTMLAnchorElement ee = el as HTMLAnchorElement;
    if ((null != ee) && (null != ee.title) && (ee.title.Contains("LINK TITLE IS HERE"))){
     //HERE I WANT TO GET THE TEXT FROM ONCLICK// String sOnClickText = ee.onclick
     //I can not find a property or method to get the text from onclick!!!
     //HERE I WILL PARSE IT TO GET 'URL IS HERE'
     //HERE I WILL REPLACE THE HREF: ee.href = 'URL IS HERE'
     //HERE I WILL GO ON: ee.click();
    }
  }
 }
```

Can someone propose a way to get **onclick** text from HTMLAnchorElement or at least from HTMLLinkElement.
Thanks in advance.
 Kaloyan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to do this the hard way. If you handle the `WebBrowser.Navigating` event, you can cancel the navigation to whichever websites that you want with the `NavigatingCancelEventArgs` object and/or replace the resulting HTML document with your own. You can find out more from the [`WebBrowser.Navigating` Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.navigating.aspx) and [`NavigatingCancelEventArgs` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigatingcanceleventargs.aspx) pages on MSDN.